# How to repeat image on view

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin

I am trying to repeat an image on a `ImageView`.
I tried using bitmap as a `src` on the imageView but the problem is that on different screen sizes the repeating is changing and i need it to be fix and look the same on all screen sizes, please help is needed

What I did so far

the ImageView

```
<ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/test"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/item_event_category_calender3"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
```

and the bitmap

```
<bitmap
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:src="@drawable/circle_grey_new"
        android:tileMode="repeat"
        android:dither="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This image is in the drawable folder. Syntax to place the png file in the ImageView below

```
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivLogo"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="180dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/devslopesprofilelogo" />
```

You need a hdpi, mdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, xxxhdpi of the same image
if you are designing for a Pixil-C tablet xxhdpi will be used
if you are designing for a Nexus 5 phone hdpi will be used
all these sizes are in the folder devslopesprofilelogo with the extension attached to the corresponding png file image

Best if you are using Constraint Layout If image is a bitmap same should be true for this type of image